# Cloned repo / npm package still has old repo URL

Tags: npm, npm-publish, npm-package

I have been working with an old repo that has several folders - each of which is a separate npm package. The repo is no longer supported, but I want to use the contents and make additions, corrections, etc. The solution was to make a duplicate repo and republish each of those packages as needed and then import them from this new source as each package is ready.

In each of the new folders that represent the npm packages, I have gone in and altered the name accordingly. However, the old url and the old gitHead is still present. I thought that this would update when I ran an npm install, but it didn't.

Do I need to change this manually or am I missing a step?

```
{
  "name": "@new-location/package-name",
  "version": "0.4.4-beta.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/old-github-location"
  },
 ...
  "xo": false,
  "gitHead": "17ee05dd56f20ad0e41b0ae5c535e44e23f32848"
}
```